# How to fix this error? Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/sendmessagetoinbox/'; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="inbox_subject" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="inbox_message"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-save send-btn">Send message to inbox</button>
        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Send message to inbox" /> -->
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="patient-id" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#inMail').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var url='<?php  echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/sendmessagetoinbox/'; ?>';
    console.log(url);
    var pId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('patientId')
    console.log(pId);   //UNDEFINED
    $(".modal-body").find('form').attr("action",url+pId);
})
```

I wish to send patient ID in action the following form. How to do this?

Comment: Which element is `event.relatedTarget`

Comment: use this $( "[name='patient-id']" ).val() to get the patient id i think `$(event.relatedTarget)` is undefined

Comment: Could you elaborate? 1) What behaviour are you expecting? 2) What behaviour are you seeing? 3) Is there any console output?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check for this 
`var pId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('patientId');` 
Try replacing with  
`var pId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('patient-id');`

I think its all about form name property

Comment: No, in jQuery it works both with **camelCase** and **hyphenated**. (In **pure JS** it would have to be **camelCase** `selectedElement.dataset.patientId`)

Comment: Also there is no element with attribute `data-patient-id`, so this could never work

Answer (score 0):

try adding id="patient-id" in put tag:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="patient-id" name="patient-id" />
```

also

```
var pId = $('#patient-id').val();
```

Comment: Why not just target selector with `name` attribute as @Cyril suggested in comments